# autoincrement column in SQL database

Tags: mysql, database, auto-increment

I have two value in one table in database which I need to autoincrement. 
First value is ID it's a primary kay and it is setup as Identity Column and have (Is Identity) - Yes in properties. 
And how setup my second value (number) to autoincrement. When I setup his property (Is Identity) yes it automaticly change Identity Column for number.

Is possible to meke autoincrement for two value in one table in sql?

Comment: Are you talking about MySQL or SQL Server? Auto increment is mysql, where Identity is SQL Server..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to have more than one identity column in a table (and I can't think of a valid reason for wanting to do so anyhow).