# autoincrement and SQL's Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, sql, asp.net-mvc-4

[autoincrement column in SQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8717544/autoincrement-column-in-sql-database)

The link answers my doubt whether or not autoincrement exists in SQL.

My current problem is like this,

I have 2 tables represented by these classes

```
public class A
{
   [Key]
   public int AId{get;set;}
   public int BId{get;set;}
   [ForeignKey("BId")]
   public virtual B pb{get;set;}
}

public class B
{
   [Key]
   public int BId{get;set;}
   public int AId{get;set;}
}
```

During initializing an object of A class, an error occurs saying that `BId can not be null`
In MySQL, I can declare a column as `AUTO_INCREMENT` then initialize the table as something like

```
INSERT INTO myTable(col2, col3, col4) VALUES('col2','col3','col4');
```

supposing that `col1` is declared as auto-increment. I'd like to do something similar with the `BId` in class A such that I don't have to set an integer to it.

Comment: Hi @asp-asp, are you using linq2sql? Entity framework? other ORM? The question is incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

That's not really how foreign keys work.

You can do just what you're asking for with a primary key, and SQL Server will set the primary key for you if it's an identity column. But for a foreign key, you should already know the value you want. You should already have an existing instance of `B` that you want to reference -- either that, or you should be creating it before you create `A`.

If you're asking to have the foreign key auto-incremented, you don't really want a foreign key, you want something else. You may want to rethink your table structure.

Answer (score 1):

If `BId` does not need a value, declare it with the `NULL` constraint in MySQL, and make the C# property nullable as well: `public int? BId`.

If you intend to set a default value for `BId`, you can declare it using the `DEFAULT` clause.

If you want to create a new `B` for each `A`, this can be done using a trigger on table `A`.